# Cannot load the target CFC abc for the relation property abc in CFC xyz

Tags: orm, coldfusion, cfc

I'm running two Applications with different Application names. Both
use the different datasources (but same database behind) and have almost the same ORM objects, but both
in their own webroot/orm folder.

While the admin app runs fine, I sometimes get an error in the public
app:
Cannot load the target CFC abc for the relation property abc in CFC
xyz.

If I look into the orm folder, all cfc are there and permissions are set properly.

After restarting ColdFusion n-times i figured out:
admin_app runs first
public_app runs second
all fine

public_app runs first
admin_app runs second
public fails until admin_app is run once

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: It would be good to see some context of what code is throwing the error.  It sounds like your admin app is doing something that the public app relies on, but again without any code you probably wont get any answers to what is causing the error.

Comment: run ORMReload(), make sure all the mappings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out, that the error occures before onApplicationStart() gets fired.
Tried to clone the database, so each app has different DSN and database. Also renamed the ORM CFCs of the public app and disabled component caching. Still the same...

I reduced the Application.cfc of the public app to minimum: http://pastebin.com/mJhSDFDi
And put a test.cfm onto the server which just outputs #now()#. Still the same...